# How to display print values on UILabel?

Tags: ios, swift, user-interface

I was wondering how do I show `print("  ", separator: "", terminator: "")` on my View UILable?

I tried creating separate functions of `separator` and `termiantor` but it doesn't work.

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: What exactly are u trying to achieve ? U wanna show entire print statement in UILabel ?

Comment: You can't, `print` displays its output on the console, you can't pipe it to the UI. What is it you are even trying to achieve, why would you want to use `print` to update your UI?

Comment: @SandeepBhandari I was just building a labyrinth. And need it to display on UILabel as it displays on my console.

Comment: @DávidPásztor  I was just building a labyrinth. And need it to display on UILabel as it displays on my console.

Comment: You should store the value you printed in a `String` variable and assign that to your label using `label.text = yourString`.

Comment: label.text = (Write your print statement value)

Comment: @DávidPásztor I see. But how do I create a separator/terminator functions and display them on UILabel as well?

Answer (score 0):

You can make use of the [joined](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/sequence/1641243-joined) function on Sequence to get the String and set that as your label's text property.

Example:

```
let values = ["Hello", "world"]
values.joined(separator: " ")
```

Output would be:

```
"Hello world"
```

Answer (score 0):

You can roll your own version of print to generate a string with separator and terminator.

Here is an example:

```
static func makeString(from strings: String..., separator: String = "", terminator: String = "") ->String {
    var result = ""
    let endLoop = strings.count - 1
    for i in 0..<endLoop {
        result.append(strings[i])
        result.append(separator)
    }
    result.append(strings[endLoop])
    result.append(terminator)
    return result
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can mimic the `print(_:,separator:,terminator:)` function for creating a formatter `String` using below `String` initializer.

```
extension String {
    init(with items:Any..., separator: String = " ", terminator: String = "\n") {
        var formattedString = items.first ?? ""
        for item in items.dropFirst() {
            formattedString = "\(formattedString)\(separator)\(item)"
        }
        self = "\(formattedString)\(terminator)"
    }
}
```

You can use it like this to assign the formatted value to a `UILabel`'s `text` property.

```
let formattedString = String(with: 1,2,3,4,separator:"...",terminator:"\t")
yourLabel.text = formattedString
```